# Trouble selecting programatically generated buttons with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, click, google-visualization

I'm having some trouble getting JQuery selectors to work with some programmatically generated divs

I'm using [google visualization table](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table.html) to display some query results with 20 results per page.  When the query returns more than 20 results (and only when there's more than 20 results) paging buttons appear at the bottom of the search results pane.

```
<div class="google-visualization-table-div-page">
  <div class="a-b-c a-d-e a-d-e-j a-d-e-o-p" title="" aria-disabled="true"
  role="button" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
    <div class="a-b-c a-d-e-f-g">
      <div class="a-b-c a-d-e-h-g">&lt;&lt;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="a-b-c a-d-e a-d-e-o-q" title="" role="button" 
style="-moz-user-select: none;" tabindex="0">
  <div class="a-b-c a-d-e-f-g">
    <div class="a-b-c a-d-e-h-g">&gt;&gt;</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

My goal is to add those same paging buttons to the top of the pane as well.  Unfortunately copying and pasting those div's above the results pane didn't work so my plan was to use jquery's click event to have the copy/pasted buttons at the top programmatically click the buttons at the bottom.

My buttons are exactly the same as the ones in the above div's just with the addition of id's.

```
<div id="top_prev" class="a-b-c a-d-e a-d-e-j a-d-e-o-p" style="-moz-user-select: none;" role="button" aria-disabled="true" title="">

<div id="top_next" class="a-b-c a-d-e a-d-e-o-q" tabindex="0" style="-moz-user-select: none;" role="button" title="">
```

Unfortunately the jquery I tried didn't work, while I was debugging I think I stumbled across the problem.  Here's my debugging JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#top_prev").click(function(){
       if ($(".a-b-c a-d-e a-d-e-j a-d-e-o-p").length ) {
          alert("top_prev success");
        }else
        {
          alert("top_prev fail");
        }
});

$("#top_next").click( function() {
if ($(".a-b-c a-d-e a-d-e-o-q").length )
{
   alert("top_next success");
}else
{
alert("top_next fail");
}
});
```

Which causes the "top_next fail" or "top_prev fail" boxes to appear even when those divs are being generated.  The javascript and html for the buttons is even being generated *after* the results pane is generated so the bottom buttons ought to be generated before the top buttons.

I guess I'm stumped as to why those selectors aren't working.  Here's the original .click jquery I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#top_prev").click(function(){
  $(".a-b-c a-d-e a-d-e-j a-d-e-o-p").click();
});

$("#top_next").click(function() {
  $(".a-b-c a-d-e a-d-e-o-q").click();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because your selector to match the elements at the bottom are wrong.

You should be using;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#top_prev").click(function(){
      $(".a-b-c.a-d-e.a-d-e-j.a-d-e-o-p").not(this).click();
    });

    $("#top_next").click(function() {
      $(".a-b-c.a-d-e.a-d-e-o-q").not(this).click();
    });
});
```

A selector in the form of `.foo .bar` is matching all elements with the class of `bar` which are a descendant of an element with class `foo` [(the descendant selector)](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/). Instead you should be using [`.foo.bar`](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) which searches for all elements with the classes `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: Won't that click itself as well? ;)

Comment: @Archer: Don't be silly, that's what that `not(this)` (now) checks against :P ;)

Comment: Now why didn't I spot that :p

Answer (score 0):

The alternative is to clone the existing buttons...

(I'm assuming here that the html you supplied is just for the paging buttons alone.)

```
var $paging = $("google-visualization-table-div-page").clone(true);
$("#containerID").append($paging);
```

`containerID` would be the ID of a div or span you add to the page and the buttons would be appended to that.

Here's reference for clone and append...

- http://api.jquery.com/clone/
- http://api.jquery.com/append/